# Finding pattern in data and structuring it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, zillow

I've a sheet where I paste data from the website, when I paste, it look like this in sheet(Page 1 and Page 2):-

Here Color Code cells represent the data of one plot, like **address**,**price**,**area** and in address there is **pincode**

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make it structured like this if you take first two column block in `P 1` in above image, I hope now it make some sense:-

- I need to grab the Pincode from address
- Address can be anywhere in columns, and below them will be there selling/renting details, like price, area etc

[image]

Don't know how to start, column has multiple property data which I want to structure

Here is the sheet link:- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M9YUR2NEc0IUvpwmzw1diMSMG9ukZw-269Rvg531WqY/edit#gid=0

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your showing image, which values are `Address, Pincode, Area, Price`, respectively?

Comment: What's happening here, there is site called Zillow.com, so I just search property there, and It shows the List of property, now I press `ctrl + A` to select the entire page content and paste it on sheet, and it appears in sheet like the way i am showing in the image, by columns I can paste multiple page data like Col A for Page 1 and Column B for Page 2 .., now when script runs it should consolidate the data and make it structured. Address here is like `17832 County Road...` and it's area and data below it, and next address comes and so on, I need to make it in such a way to make it structured

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand which are the values of `Address, Pincode, Area, Price` in your showing image. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your expected values, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Comment: Hi, would you consider clarifying the desired output here?

Comment: I agree with @Iamblichus 's suggestion.

Comment: @Tanaike I edited the post, with desired output, I hope I make sense now

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know Javascript?

Comment: Yes, I am not good in JS, intermediate. I tried ,But that didn't worked. I thought of building the logic to find the empty value, and consider it as start of next address, but that also didn't worked. At last I posted here, hoping to get some suggestions.

Comment: Tbh, this looks like a wild goose chase. You should rather directly scrape or get the data directly from zillow api.

Comment: Ya, but I guess they turned off their API because of abuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a fixed order of the data, starting at the address after that the price and after that the area

**Delete unrelated data to avoid bugs**

```
function findPatterns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
// ranges to process
  let columns = ['A24:A87', 'B24:B267', 'C24:C174']
  let res = []
  let arr = []
  columns.forEach(column => {
    let range = ssname.getRange(column).getValues().flat().filter(r => r)
    range.forEach(e => {
      let addres = e.match(/, CO \d/)
      let price = e.match(/^\$\d+(,\d+)?/gm)
      let area = e.match(/sqft|acres/)
      // added the check variable 
      let days = e.match(/Zillow/)
      if (addres != null) {
        let pincode = e.match(/, CO (\d+)/).pop()
        arr.push(e, pincode)
      }
      if (price != null) {
        arr.push(e)
      }
      // check if its the line of the days
      if(days != null){
         arr.push(e.match(/\d+/)[0])

         res.push(arr)
         arr = []
      }
      if (area != null) {
        arr.push(area[0])
        let num = e.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)
        if (num != null) {
          arr.push(num[0])
        } else {
          arr.push('')
        }
        
      }
    })
  })
  res.forEach((el, idx) => {
    range = ssname.getRange('H' + (idx + 2) + ':L' + (idx + 2))
    range.setValues([el])
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can I also add days too?? like some of address has `2 days on Zillow` or something, can I add them too, it comes after area

Comment: @ankit_dot Look edit, if no days row exists it wont work prapuly